# Form post if password input is current password in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to check if entered password is **currently logged in** users password and give error message if not.

I have profile editing form with name, email etc.

Last input in form is password input.

How can I check if password that is entered is current password?

In EditProfileRequest i tried (custom request file, made with artisan):

```
  public function rules() {
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id,
        'country_code' => 'digits_between:1,4|numeric',
        'phone' => 'digits_between:5,12|numeric',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

but it rejected form with correct password.
Then I tried adding to controller this part:

```
if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), Auth::user()->password)) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInputs();
    }
```

this worked but I don't get any errors for user and I don't know how to add custom error messages, since I am using built-in validator.

Comment: So at the end I used:
`if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), Auth::user()->password)) {
 return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['password' => 'Incorrect password']);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the custom error message as following.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
//Here you are checking your inputs with the validation rules that you are created. 

if ($validator->fails())
{
    //If the validation fails, check for the password validation too and return the error. 
    if (!Hash::check(Input::get('password'), Auth::user()->password)) {
        return Redirect::back()
                          ->withInputs()
                          ->withErrors(['login' => 'Your custom Error Msg'])
                          ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else{
               return Redirect::back()
                          ->withInputs()
                          ->withErrors(['login' => 'Your custom Error Msg']);
   }
}
```

As a short answer for your question to get a custom error message:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInputs()->withErrors(['login'=>'custom msg']);
```

Comment: I removed 'withErrors($validator)' and 'withInputs()' and changed "['login', 'Your custom Error Msg']" to "['login' => 'Your custom Error Msg']" and got it working, also all other inputs were correct (ones before changing).

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I can understand, but I always edit my answers later after the initial submit.

Comment: I agree, I would like to have explanation too, like does this Validator::make overwrite the builtin one and also where should People put it.

Comment: `Validation::make` is not overwriting anything. It's just performing the validation with the rules that you created for the particular model.

Comment: @JilsonThomas and now you made it like all the other answeres in world wide web. Maybe it is correct approach, but since I said that I am using built-in validator then all the other rules are already checked with that and I only need check one other and I think creating new validator for that is not necessary.Please correct me if I'm wrong,

Comment: Actually I was just combining all the checks together. You just have to do the password check in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you display the errors in your login page.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

You can check displaying validation errors on this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: This is not login page, but profile editing form as said in question description. And I have this part implemented, thanks.

Comment: I see. Does your form has the csrf_token field?

Comment: Yes, got it working. (See Jilson Thomas answer and my comment on question)

Comment: Glad it's working. I actually wanted to comment on that answer but my reputation points is not enough to do it. So trying to help more people now :)